# Exclude certain products from Magento sitemap.xml generation

Tags: product, magento-1, sitemaps

I need to make sure a handful of products are **NOT** in the generated `Sitemap.xml` file in Magento. I found a couple of example for things like CMS Pages but nothing for doing product pages, and more then 1 product. I am brand new to Magento

Anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Out of the box, no, there's no way to exclude certain products from the sitemap generated by Magento's `Catalog -> Google Sitemap` feature.

If I was going to go about doing this programmatically, modern versions of Magento (checked in the 1.7.x branch, this might be around in earlier/EE versions) use the following resource model class

```
Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product
```

to fetch a list of products.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Sitemap/Model/Sitemap.php
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sitemap/catalog_product')->getCollection($storeId);
```

This is not a standard Magento CRUD model, and `getCollection` does not return a collection object.  Instead, `getCollection` manually queries the database for these products.

If I was going to implement functionality that prevented certain products from showing up in the site map, I'd try to either

1. A class rewrite the `getCollection` method which calls the `parent::getCollection`, and then manually filters out any products from the array
2. A class rewrite on `_addFilter` which calls the parent::_addFilter method, and then adds an additional WHERE clause(s) to the `_select` to exclude the specific product(s).  Sort of a hack, but it's the only method where you have access to the `_select` object used to query the database.  Ideally you'd want to have some sort of global/static flag so you only added your new WHERE clause(s) once.

Answer (score 9):

Since Magento 1.9.0. you can do this without touching any core file.

There are two new events you can observe:

```
sitemap_categories_generating_before
```

```
sitemap_products_generating_before
```

To exclude products based on attribute, you can do this:

### Event lookup

Add an observer to `sitemap_products_generating_before`

```
app\code\community\My\Module\etc\config.xml
```

```xml
<events>
    <sitemap_products_generating_before>
        <observers>
            <my_module>
                <class>my_module/observer</class>
                <method>excludeProductsFromSitemap</method>
            </my_module>
        </observers>
    </sitemap_products_generating_before>
</events>
```

### Event execution

```
app\code\community\My\Module\Model\Observer.php
```

```php
public function excludeProductsFromSitemap(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
   $collection = $observer->getCollection();
   $items = $collection->getItems();

   $excludeIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
       ->getCollection()
       ->setStoreId($observer->getStoreId()) # requieres Magento 1.9.3.0
       ->addAttributeToFilter('use_in_sitemap', 0)
       ->getAllIds();

   foreach ($excludeIds as $id) {
       unset($items[$id]);
   }
   
   $collection->setItems($items);
}
```

### Add attribute

1. add a product attribute `yes/no` named `use_in_sitemap` (maybe default value `yes`)
2. add this attribute to all attribute sets
3. set the products you want to exclude to `no`

***Note**: until Magento 1.9.3.0 the attribute should be set to `global` scope.*

Answer (score 1):

You can disable those products or set the visibility field to 'Not visible individually'. In the sitemap only enabled and visible products are listed.
If you need those products enabled, just disable them, build sitemap.xml  and enable them again.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can do the following -:

1. Create an attribute against product i.e. `exclude_from_sitemap` (Yes / No)
2. Overwrite `Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product` class and modify `getCollection` function by adding filter to your new attribute i.e exclude from sitemap

If you are not a developer then the following module can help achieving the above but ofcourse it is paid extension

http://www.scommerce-mage.co.uk/magento-extensions/magento-google-site-map-exclusion.html