# observer is not firing on server but fired on local

Tags: event-observer, model

I had a look around the site but can't find any existing threads would solve my problem. I have an extension to exclude some products and categories before rendering the sitemap.xml. I use Mage::log to record if those methods are fired.

While I tested on local machine, everything works fine. They correctly excluded some specified categories and products and also generated log files in `/var/log` folder.

When I deployed the codes onto the server, only method `beforeLoadLayout` worked and logs generated.

The methods `excludeProductsFromSitemap` and `excludeCategoriesFromSitemap` are not working at all. Neither logs generate.

- Cache is flushed every time I update codes
- Compilation is always disabled

Here is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <My_Ext>
        <version>0.1.2</version>
    </My_Ext>
</modules>
<global>
    <!-- models -->
    <models>
        <myext>
            <class>My_Ext_Model</class>
        </myext>
    </models>
    <!-- helpers -->
    <helpers>
        <myext>
            <class>My_Ext_Helper</class>
        </myext>
    </helpers>
    <events>
        <sitemap_products_generating_before>
            <observers>
                <myext>
                    <class>myext/observer</class>
                    <method>excludeProductsFromSitemap</method>
                </myext>
            </observers>
        </sitemap_products_generating_before>
        <sitemap_categories_generating_before>
            <observers>
                <myext>
                    <class>myext/observer</class>
                    <method>excludeCategoriesFromSitemap</method>
                </myext>
            </observers>
        </sitemap_categories_generating_before>
    </events>
</global>
<frontend>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
            <observers>
                <myext>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>myext/observer</class>
                    <method>beforeLoadLayout</method>
                </myext>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

I also tried other way to write the `<events>` like below but result is the same as above:

```
    <events>
        <sitemap_products_generating_before>
            <observers>
                <myext>
                    <class>My_Ext_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>excludeProductsFromSitemap</method>
                </myext>
            </observers>
        </sitemap_products_generating_before>
        <sitemap_categories_generating_before>
            <observers>
                <myext>
                    <class>My_Ext_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>excludeCategoriesFromSitemap</method>
                </myext>
            </observers>
        </sitemap_categories_generating_before>
    </events>
```

Here is my Observer.php:

```
<?php
class My_Ext_Model_Observer {
public function excludeCategoriesFromSitemap( Varien_Event_Observer $observer ) {
    Mage::log( 'in excludeCategoriesFromSitemap', null, '000_debug.log' );
    $event      = $observer->getEvent();
    $collection = $event->getCollection();
    $items      = $this->getFilteredItems( $observer, 'category' );
    $collection->setItems( $items );
}

public function excludeProductsFromSitemap( Varien_Event_Observer $observer ) {
    Mage::log( 'in excludeProductsFromSitemap', null, '000_debug.log' );
    $event      = $observer->getEvent();
    $collection = $event->getCollection();
    $items      = $this->getFilteredItems( $observer, 'product' );
    $collection->setItems( $items );
}

private function getFilteredItems( $observer, $type ) {
    // Not called by event directly and works fine so not copied
    return $items;
}

public function beforeLoadLayout( Varien_Event_Observer $observer ) {
    Mage::log( 'in beforeLoadLayout', null, '000_debug.log' );
    // Works find on local and server so not copied
}
```

}

I also tried to writing the class like `class My_Ext_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Observer` but problem remains the same.

I appreciate if anyone can come up with anything I haven't tried. Lots of thanks.

Comment: Check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4528/exclude-certain-products-from-magento-sitemap-xml-generation/4529#answer-4529

Comment: Thanks @adarsh-khatri, I will have a look of that one now.

Comment: @adarsh-khatri, that actually works! Wonderfull! Thanks for the hint. I will come back and upvote your help when I have more rep.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with @adarsh-khatri's help.

First of all, using `<rewrite>` instead of firing an `<event>` before rendering the sitemap.xml. So I removed the `events` and `methods` then added `rewrite` as below:

> app/code/local/My/Ext/config.xml

```
<conig>
...
<global>
    <!-- models -->
    <models>
        <canoupdater>
            <class>My_Ext_Model</class>
        </canoupdater>
        <sitemap_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <catalog_category>My_Ext_Model_Resource_Catalog_Category</catalog_category>
            </rewrite>
        </sitemap_resource>
        <sitemap_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <catalog_product>My_Ext_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product</catalog_product>
            </rewrite>
        </sitemap_resource>
    </models>
...
</global>
...
</config>
```

I then added two files:

> app/code/local/My/Ext/Model/Resource/Catalog/Category.php

```
<?php
class My_Ext_Model_Resource_Catalog_Category extends Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Category {
/**
 * Get category collection array
 *
 * @param int $storeId
 * @return array
 */
public function getCollection( $storeId ) {
    /* @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
    if (!$store) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->_select = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->select()
        ->from($this->getMainTable())
        ->where($this->getIdFieldName() . '=?', $store->getRootCategoryId());

    $categoryRow = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->fetchRow($this->_select);
    if (!$categoryRow) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->_select = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->select()
        ->from(array('main_table' => $this->getMainTable()), array($this->getIdFieldName()))
        ->where('main_table.path LIKE ?', $categoryRow['path'] . '/%');

    $storeId = (int)$store->getId();

    /** @var $urlRewrite Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category_Url_Rewrite_Interface */
    $urlRewrite = $this->_factory->getCategoryUrlRewriteHelper();
    $urlRewrite->joinTableToSelect($this->_select, $storeId);

    $this->_addFilter($storeId, 'is_active', 1);

    $entries = $this->_loadEntities();
    foreach ( $entries as $k => $v ) {
        $obj = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' )->load( $k );
        if ( // My logic is true ) {
            unset( $entries[$k] ); // Remove this entry from the array
        }
    }
    return $entries;
}
```

> app/code/local/My/Ext/Model/Resource/Catalog/Product.php

```
<?php
class My_Ext_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product extends Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product {
/**
 * Get product collection array
 *
 * @param int $storeId
 * @return array
 */
public function getCollection( $storeId ) {
    /* @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
    if (!$store) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->_select = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->select()
        ->from(array('main_table' => $this->getMainTable()), array($this->getIdFieldName()))
        ->join(
            array('w' => $this->getTable('catalog/product_website')),
            'main_table.entity_id = w.product_id',
            array()
        )
        ->where('w.website_id=?', $store->getWebsiteId());

    $storeId = (int)$store->getId();

    /** @var $urlRewrite Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Url_Rewrite_Interface */
    $urlRewrite = $this->_factory->getProductUrlRewriteHelper();
    $urlRewrite->joinTableToSelect($this->_select, $storeId);

    $this->_addFilter($storeId, 'visibility',
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds(), 'in'
    );
    $this->_addFilter($storeId, 'status',
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getVisibleStatusIds(), 'in'
    );

    $entries = $this->_loadEntities();
    foreach ( $entries as $k => $v ) {
        $obj = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )->load( $k );
        if ( // If my logic is true ) {
            unset( $entries[$k] ); // Remove the entry from the array
        }
    }
    return $entries;
}
```

This solved my problem and I hope this would help others who have the similar problems.

Comment: Please check you previous code ... using events is the right way to go.

Comment: @sv3n, I believe using event will definitely work but at the moment I can't find where goes wrong. If you have any idea please state in comments or post in reply. I appreciate.

Comment: Which Magento version do you use?

Comment: Magento 1.9.13 Enterprise

Comment: Can you please check `Mage_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap` or `Enterprise_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap` if there is any `dispatchEvent` in `generateXml()`.

Comment: Yes, there are two in the `Sitemap.php`.  `Mage::dispatchEvent('sitemap_categories_generating_before', array(
            'collection' => $categories
        ));` and `Mage::dispatchEvent('sitemap_products_generating_before', array(
            'collection' => $products
        ));`