# How to exclude certain products from Magento sitemap.xml generation in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, sitemaps

I found similar solution for this([Exclude certain products from Magento sitemap.xml generation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4528/exclude-certain-products-from-magento-sitemap-xml-generation)) for version less than magento 2.0, I wanted a solution in magento 2. Being a developer I would like to do it on my own, rather than using a 3rd party extension

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this below extension help you solve this :

https://redchamps.com/xml-sitemap-exclude-url-magento-2-extension.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply being a developer I would like to do it on my own

Comment: That's great @SidharthSatheesh.