# How to exclude specific Products, Categories and CMS Pages from sitemap.xml generation in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, category, cms-pages, sitemaps

I need to create a custom module that allows excluding/skipping the Products, Categories and CMS Pages URLs from generating in sitemap.xml. I had tried [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4528/exclude-certain-products-from-magento-sitemap-xml-generation) solution for Magento 1, How could I do it in Magento 2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Answer given a base on Magento  2.3.1 Opensource**

*There are 3 files, the Sitemap related data of Products, Categories, and CMS Pages is coming*

`Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Category:getCollection()`

`Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product:getCollection()`

`Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Cms\Page:getCollection()`

So, you want to skip any product/category/page from sitemap.xml you have to work on that related class and its method.

So, create [**plugin**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) on required classes and changes the out of that required  `getCollection()` method.

#### Or You can work on

Or you can work om `Magento\Sitemap\Model\ItemProvider\Composite` argument list

See `di.xml` of `vendor/magento/module-sitemap/etc/di.xml`. On below code

```
<type name="Magento\Sitemap\Model\ItemProvider\Composite">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="itemProviders" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="categoryProvider" xsi:type="object">Magento\Sitemap\Model\ItemProvider\Category</item>
            <item name="cmsPageProvider" xsi:type="object">Magento\Sitemap\Model\ItemProvider\CmsPage</item>
            <item name="productProvider" xsi:type="object">Magento\Sitemap\Model\ItemProvider\Product</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Suppose, I want to change at the Cms page list of sitemap. To build a module and that `cmsPageProvider` argument value.

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Sitemap\Model\ItemProvider\Composite">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="itemProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="cmsPageProvider" xsi:type="object">MyVendor\MymoDule\Model\ItemProvider\MyCmsPage</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

It means `MyVendor\MymoDule\Model\ItemProvider\MyCmsPage` Class will call On cms Page collection classes at sitemap  generation  instead of `Magento\Sitemap\Model\ItemProvider\CmsPage`

Comment: Note that for products specifically, there is a public method `prepareSelectStatement` on `Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product` that is specifically intended as a plugin extension point for modifying the query (so says the PHPDoc comment).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to exclude or skip certain products, categories, and CMS pages from the sitemap.xml generation in Magento 2. Some of the possible methods are:

•  Using a plugin or a class rewrite to modify the getCollection() method of the resource model classes that fetch the sitemap data for products, categories, and CMS pages

•  Using an observer to listen to the sitemap_products_generating_before and sitemap_categories_generating_before events and filter out the items that you want to exclude from the sitemap

•  Using a custom attribute or a configuration option to mark the products, categories, and CMS pages that you want to exclude from the sitemap and then use that attribute or option in the sitemap generation logic

•  Using a [custom extension](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-google-sitemap-exclusion.html) that provides the functionality to exclude products, categories, and CMS pages from the sitemap.

I hope this information is helpful