# How to add cms page URL in sitemap.xml

Tags: cms, magento2.3.1, cms-pages, sitemaps

How to created `sitemap.xml` last week in my production site.

Today I have created a new CMS page. How do I add this page's URL to `sitemap.xml`?

Please provide me a solution.

Comment: try this link :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297939/how-to-exclude-specific-products-categories-and-cms-pages-from-sitemap-xml-gene

Comment: CMS pages should automatically appear. Maybe your sitemap is not being generated on schedule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMS pages should be included automatically.

Check generation settings

```
Stores /  Settings / Configuration / Catalog / XML Sitemap
```

In the ‘Generation Settings’ set ‘Enables’ to ‘Yes’:

Set the ‘Start Time’ for future update and set ‘Frequency’ to ‘Daily’ if you want it to be renewed in this regime.

If that's all set it could be a permission issue. Consider configuring to output to a different locations. Make sure that location has read write access.

```
Marketing / Seo & Search / Site Map
```